# AWS Lambda: Sending a video template to messenger causes lambda to timeout

Tags: aws-lambda, messenger, facebook-chatbot

We are using Claudia.js to hook our bot, hosted on Lambda, to Facebook.

It works well until we want to send a template for a video. We are getting timeouts unless when but the lambda execution limit to up to a minute.

In the client the timeouts cause duplicated instances of the videos appear on the chat window.

We are not sure if this is a limitation of how Claudia.js is designed (it will always wait for a 200 from Facebook, thus keeping the function alive) or otherwise how we could configure the system - or use some alternative solution- to avoid this timeout problem.

We have already optimized the video, this helps a bit but not much.

Comment: You ever resolve this? I'm facing the same issue using claudiajs, AWS Lambda and facebook. My timeout is at 3 minutes, so it isn't due to a short timeout (which I saw from your initial github issue). I was also told: "Hm, then it seems to be something else. It can cause it because fb retries sending payload if it fails, etc."

Answer (score 1):

The best practice and correct way to handle the situation after debugging is the following:

1. Submit the video and upload it using the [Attachment Upload API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/attachment-upload-api)
2. Use the attachment_id returned from Step 1 when sending response, for example:

```js
    let VIDEO_PAYLOAD = {
        "attachment": {
          "type": "template",
          "payload": {
             "template_type": "media",
             "elements": [
                {
                    "media_type": "video",
                    "attachment_id": "**<ATTACHMENT ID>**",                    
                }          
             ]
          }
        }   
     };
```